# Put branding over tv signal

Tags: video, streaming

Im trying to figure out the most clean way to put custom content (being text or picture for branding) over standard tv signal for a business that want to show their logos and such in the tv´s they have in their place.

So far, the most promising solution involves taking a single source for tv to a capture device and stream it with a regular broadcaster software (something like OBS) through the internal network or to the same machine and distribute the feed over coax or whatever.

Thw downside (or upside, depending on how you look at it) of this approach is that all tvs will have the same channel on the screen, and I was looking for a way to make it more flexible and transparent, without having to actually put a computer with a capture device (maybe a Raspberry Pi + a cheap card would do the trick, but I think that´s just overkill, and really a waste of energy) in the middle of the tv and the sat/cable box.

So you know of any way to add text or image in front of a tv stream, whatever that may be that doesn´t involve what I´ve just described? Maybe a tv model that will allow to load text or bmp/jpegs/etc from a thumbstick; or a settop box, DVR, magic little device that allows to load content to put in front of the signal? It´s a pretty trivial stuff, and I´m a bit surprised I haven´t been able to find something like this.

Cheers,

Comment: Do you want unlimited, ad hoc channel selection behind the branding, or is there a small number of allowable channels? The first case requires a device at each TV, but the second case could be centrally controlled.

Comment: The first one would be ideal, but building a solution from scratch I think would be expensive. For the second case I was thinking on streaming several channels on the same way I described, it´s not what I want exactly, but would be a fair compromise, given the fact I can´t think of any other solution.

Answer (score 1):

In [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) you have an overlay feature among the out-of-the-box effects (Tools->Effects and Filters->Video Effects->Overlay). The overlay can be a logo, de-logo eraser, or text. You can run VLC centrally and restream the TV channel, or you can run it in a Linux settop box and control it centrally via its internal built-in web server, via telnet, or via the Lua interface. You can also make more complex overlays such as PIP (picture in picture) but that requires some mastering of the VLC command syntax.